# Using of types that was defined inside a template class

Tags: c++11

I want to use a type that was defined inside a template class. How can I do it?

```
template < typename A, typename B>
struct internal {
    const static std::string value; 
    typedef B type;
};

template < typename A > using external = struct internal<A,  int>;

external::type object;
```

Comment: `external` is a one-parameter template. It has to be `external<SomeType>::type`

Comment: You see that B was defined. external::type doesn't depend from template parameter A

Comment: Does too. For all you know, there's a specialization of `internal<Something, int>` that defines `type` to something other than `int`.